# Posting a file to a web service with Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, guzzle

I've been trying for several hours to make a POST request that sends a file.

First tried a simple `file_get_contents()` with stream context, doesn't seem to work. I never get a response back while the GET on a different URL works.

I searched on the web for an HTTP client and found Guzzle which was downloaded 400k times on Packagist; I decided to try out this technology. Well documented but, alas, getting an error also when posting that damn file.

```
$request = $client
    ->post('/files/')
    ->addPostFields(array('comments' => 'no value'))
    ->addPostFile('file', 'test.doc')
    ->setAuth($this->username, $this->password);
```

It took me hours of reading and scouring the web to find out that I had a "417 Expectation Failed" issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>417 Expectation Failed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Expectation Failed</h1>
<p>The expectation given in the Expect request-header
field could not be met by this server.
The client sent<pre>
    Expect: 100-Continue, 100-Continue
</pre>
</p><p>Only the 100-continue expectation is supported.</p>
</body></html>
```

After more searching on the web, I ended up reading on the "Expect: 100-continue" header that was sent automatically by Guzzle, so I tried:

```
$request->removeHeader('expect');
```

I now end up with a bad request:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Request header field is missing ':' separator.<br />
<pre>
zzle/3.7.3 curl/7.15.5 PHP/5.3.27</pre>
</p>
</body></html>
```

Printing the request headers to find that : missing, i get:

```
var_dump($request->__toString());

POST /files/ HTTP/1.1
Host: nunc57.qc.bell.ca
User-Agent: Guzzle/3.7.3 curl/7.15.5 PHP/5.3.27
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Authorization: Basic bm92YTpzeW5hcHNl
```

Now I'm really stumped, I hope someone has already found a solution to this issue. I'm getting really tired of all this :(

Comment: Can you post to the target URL using a web browser? If so, try using your browser's tools to see what headers are supplied. Also, posting to `/files/` looks a bit odd, are you sure there's not something at the end of that? Or, should it be `/files` without the trailing slash? Lastly, build a simple file upload system locally in PHP to test on - you may find that the server you're having problems with is being especially fussy about something; knowing that your Guzzle system works with an ordinary file upload page will be helpful!

Comment: The service endpoint you'r hitting might be non-compliant, or you may have found a bug. Try using a rest client like [wiztools's](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) and see if you can get the request to work that way.

Comment: Oh the service works, i built it completly from the ground up and the html portion works fine, even the get portion using application/json or vnd.xxx.yyy.type+xml works, only the post doesn't seem to work. I'll try the solution from @halfer about removing the trailing slash and i'll look again at my chrome developper tool as to what is hapenning when i post manually using the html interface

Comment: Oh well, i had to do different changes to achieve perfect functionality, but it was more due to me not doings things correctly, the main fix was simply removing the trailing slash @halfer so please write a quick answer so i can flag it as the good one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder whether POSTing to `/files/` (with a trailing slash) might be causing problems. Perhaps this forces an internal redirect and upsets Goutte, but not a web browser? I'd try adjusting your page so that you POST either to `/files` or `/files/something`.

If you can POST okay to the target URL using a web browser, I'd also suggest you record the request headers using browser tools, and see if there are any headers that could be added to your Guzzle request.